# Reducer not connected to redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying with simple object reducer to display data in a component. But the state of that object is not getting upto the component. The code structure as below.

labels.js:

```
  export default function () {
    return [
    { id: 1, name: "Labels1"},
    { id: 2, name: "Labels2"}
    ]
}
```

allReducer(index):

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import labelsReducer from './labels';

const allReducers = combineReducers({
    labels: labelsReducer
});

export default allReducers;
```

store:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import allReducers from './reducers/index'

function configureStore() {
    return createStore(allReducers);
}

export default configureStore;
```

APP

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Labels from './components/Labels.jsx';

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import configureStore from './store';

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={configureStore()}>
      <div className="App">
        <Labels />
      </div>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Labels:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Labels extends React.Component {
    labelsList() {
        this.props.labels.map((label) => {
            return (
                <li key={label.id}>{labels.name}</li>
            )
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <label>{this.labelsList()}</label>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return (
        labels: state.labels
    )
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Labels);
```

> Why I am getting below error. What is the issue on connect state with
>   reducer ./src/components/Labels.jsx   Line 9:37:  'labels' is not
>   defined  no-undef   Line 23:9:  'labels' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: How are you connecting it? It's good to provide all relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`connect`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) function from react-redux. Import at the top:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
```

And at the bottom of your component, do:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(labelsList)
```

EDIT:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return (
        labels: state.labels
    )
}
```

should be:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        labels: state.labels
    }
}
```

(note the curly brackets for returning the object, not standard parentheses)

and `<li key={label.id}>{labels.name}</li>` should be `label.name`. `labels` doesn't exist as a local variable in the scope.

Comment: Updated labels.jsx file. I am only using reducer(No Action files), just trying to display the data from reducer.

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
    this.props.labels.map((label) => {
        return (
            <li key={label.id}>{labels.name}</li>
        )
    })
```

`{labels.name}` should be `{label.name}`

In your callback function, you have a local variable `label`, as well as `this.state.labels`, but there isn't one that's simply called `labels`.